# Как получить данные из БД и вставить его в ассоциативный массив

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Всем привет!

В бд есть таблица `users` и из неё мне нужно вытащить в массив данные о пользователе из столбца `role`

Написал такой скрипт, но почему то он не работает

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT `role` FROM `users`");
$user_info = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $user_info[] = array_values($row);
}
print_r($user_info);
```

Таблица из бд:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `mysqli_` и `mysql_` вы уж определитесь с библиотекой

Comment: А данные о каком именно пользователе вы получили вам не важно ? Ибо ваш запрос получает только сами role, а к кому они относятся не получает, потому как других колонок вы в select не указали

Comment: @Mike Я так понял, вот такой запрос будет правильнее: ```SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `role` = `admin` ``` ? Т.Ибо мне нужно узнать, у какого пользователя есть ```role``` ```admin```, а у кого нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно в `mysqli_query` не хватает ссылки на соединение (см. [примеры](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-examples))

Плюс в одном месте у вас написано `mysqli_`, в другом `mysql_`

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT `role` FROM `users`";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
                            ^---- ОЧЕНЬ ВАЖНО!!
    
    $user_info = [];

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $user_info[] = array_values($row);
    }

    /* удаление выборки */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    print_r($user_info);
}
```

Comment: Всё равно почему-то не работает. Я немного изменил запрос, теперь он выглядит так: ```SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `role` = `admin` ``` и поменял ```$link``` на ```$connect``` (т.к у меня это именно ```$connect```)

Comment: @realHikkan надо `SELECT * FROM \`users\` WHERE \`role\` = 'admin'`  - кавычки у строк должны быть одинарными